# How can I get all views that have value in the tag attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 7 views has `android:tag="92832380"` in the same layout and I tried to get these views using `findViewWithTag` but it returns 1 view (first view) only so what is the best way to get all views that has `92832380` value?

**Edit**

According to the comments discussion below, I found this way to solve the problem but is it a good way, or is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: java or kotlin ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Java

Comment: instead of doing this, rather explain _why_ you're using tags in the first place ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Okay it's a long story but I'll try to explain, My app support 7 languages, and I want to add two fonts for each language in the assets folder (bold font and light font), I want to use the tag attribute to know if this view should take bold font or light font. When I say views I mean TextView

Comment: to support a multilingual app you can have styles for each language and have font attribute there then you can use the style for your views . having tag for this thing will only make it complicated. If your app shows multiple language at same time then also you can set a different style to Views. Since you already added tag i.e you already know before hand which textview will have which font  so it should be hard to do .

Comment: @ADM I thought of that before to create themes.xml for each language but two problems made me hesitant to do it that way. The first problem is repeating. In main themes.xml it contains 368 lines if I want to do it that way then I should copy 368 lines 7 times for each language. The second problem is the fonts attributes. how to create an attribute in themes.xml for bold font and another attribute for the light font?

Comment: You don't have to copy everything just copy the part which you want to be different . To use font you have to create a font.xml file . Just look for how to use custom font in android . U will get it .

Comment: @ADM Check the update, please.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Check the update, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this way

```
fun getViewsByTag(rootView: ViewGroup, tag: String): ArrayList<View>? {
        val views = ArrayList<View>()
        val childCount = rootView.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = rootView.getChildAt(i)
            if (child is ViewGroup) {
                views.addAll(getViewsByTag(child, tag)!!)
            }
            val tagObj = child.tag
            if (tagObj != null && tagObj == tag) {
                views.add(child)
            }
        }
        return views
    }
```

If you have multiple types of view with same tag you can identify them by `is` like `if (child is EditText)`